# cgminer with an nvidia 710m GPU

Tags: cgminer

Im trying to get my nvidia gpu working with cgminer 3.7.2 
(windows 8 x64)
how could i make it work?
here is what my list devices says

```
CL platform 1 name: NVIDIA CUDA
CL platform 1 version: OpenCL 1.1 CUDA 6.0.1
```

When i try to run cgminer -d 1, It wont run.

```
command line options set a device that doesn't exist
```

Comment: What Crypto are you trying to mine?